# Add SQL trigger to always remove leading/trailing spaces in column for updates/inserts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I insert a row into my table, I need one of the columns to never have a leading/trailing space. Would using a trigger cause a lot of overhead delay if the table is used a lot? If so, is there a better way to do it?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (item, qty) VALUES (' test ', 2)
SELECT item FROM MyTable
```

The above should return "test" instead of " test ".

Edit: Please note this IS a last resort, we cannot sanitize all the raw files being imported and we would have to update many of our applications.

Comment: I think you're better off with a check constraint with a wildcard. `constraint __chk check Item not like ' %' and item not like '% '`. That will prevent any bad data from getting in in the first place.

Comment: or use: `INSERT INTO MyTable (item, qty) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(' test ')), 2);`   (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/peZXShBy))

Comment: If you have no control over the insert statement itself, then use a calculated column.  Do not use a trigger.  If you have control over the insert statement then do what luuk says.

Comment: If you cannot sanitize your data at source then your *last* resort is an instead-of trigger - details available in the documentation.

Comment: This is correct, I'm unable to sanitize all data because we have many raw files from many destinations and would have to update all our applications.

Comment: If you want the data to be correct immediately, then yes, trigger is a way to go. Otherwise you could run some job that cleans up stuff. Another alternative is to trim stuff on *usage*, but maybe that's not feasible either

Answer (score 4):

A trigger *is* an option, but typically not what you want to reach for first.

A trigger does introduce overhead, and IMHO more importantly, complexity. Triggers are generally not the sort of thing people frequently expect to be on a table, and thus they may get overlooked during troubleshooting or performance improvement. In my entire career, I think I might have written two triggers for production code, and those were for really weird cases. So yes, it's an option, but I think you're probably better off solving this a different way.

Generally, you're a lot better off if you can clean your data as it comes in. If you have a stored procedure inserting your data, simply tun `ltrim(rtrim(myvalue))` when you insert it, and it will strip off leading/trailing whitespace (or `trim(myValue)` on SQL2017+).

Additionally, if the field *cannot* have leading or trailing white space, **make a constraint to enforce that!**. A check constraint like `constraint MyCheckConstraint check (item not like ' %' and item not like '% ')` will *guarantee* you will never have any rows with leading/trailing spaces.

Of course the way it guarantees that is by throwing an exception if you try to do so, which is why sanitizing those values in the insertion proc is so important.

Pretty much the only scenario I would think a trigger would be the right solution to this is if you're getting this data directly from a raw file, and you don't have any point in the loading process to ain between getting the file and, say, `bcp`-ing it into your database to do the cleaning. And even then, my suggestion would be to load the "dirty" data into a staging table, then run SQL to clean the data and insert it into your live table.

Comment: Totally agree. Trimming should be done by application. Give the app devs fair warning and a date by which they must comply, then on that date define the constraint. Adding a trigger is doubly wrong because it hides the real problem and pours concrete around bad app code.

Comment: That's the problem, there are many sources that update and insert into the table that handling all exceptions would be an issue. It's not just 1 application, we're also using raw files.

Comment: Another option, although it's totally pasting over the problem is you could add a computed column to the table which is basically `ItemClean as ltrim(rtrim(Item))`